# Definir ID manualmente com Hibernate em modo AUTO

Tags: java, hibernate

Olá, gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de definir o ID manualmente quando se esta usando o hibernate em modo de auto incremento.

Eu quero que ele use o auto incremento mas em algumas situações especificas preciso consultar no banco os IDs existentes e definir o ID manualmente.

Mas toda vez que tento ele ignora o ID que eu coloquei na entidade e põe outro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, tem como, para que isso seja possível faça o seguinte (utilizando esta [questão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194721/bypass-generatedvalue-in-hibernate-merge-data-not-in-db/3218642#3218642) como referência):

Adicione isto ao seu atributo 'id':

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator="IdOrGenerated")
@GenericGenerator(name="IdOrGenerated",
              strategy="....UseIdOrGenerate"
)
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
private Integer id;
```

E adicione esta classe:

```
import org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator;
...
public class UseIdOrGenerate extends IdentityGenerator {
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(UseIdOrGenerate.class.getName());

@Override
public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object obj) throws HibernateException {
if (obj == null) throw new HibernateException(new NullPointerException()) ;

if ((((EntityWithId) obj).getId()) == null) {
    Serializable id = super.generate(session, obj) ;
    return id;
} else {
    return ((EntityWithId) obj).getId();

}
}
```